# C++/CLI Project not Creating AssemblyInfo.cpp

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, visual-studio-2013

I have a C++/CLI project that does not create an AssemblyInfo.cpp file it does however make a Version.h file.  From my research it seems that C++/CLI projects make AssemblyInfo.cpp files by default.

Is there a compiler flag or a setting that can be changed to make this happen?

Comment: It is part of the project template, there isn't any way to not get the file.  Or for that matter get a Version.h file, that's not included in the project template.  You must be using the wrong template.

Comment: You are right, I found the AssemblyInfo was moved to a different folder in the settings. Thanks!

Comment: So post your solution as an answer and accept it, please. In this way people will see immediately that the question is solved and how and doesn't need a solution anymore. ;)